# Ghost install npm

Tags: ghost-blog

I get an error when I run this command:

```
npm install --production
```

Help please.

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/root/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab088.4
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! cwd /root
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.4
npm ERR! path /root/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried to execute the command in the directory with Ghost. And came out this error:

> sqlite3@2.2.0 install /var/www/node_modules/sqlite3
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! sqlite3@2.2.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@2.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab088.4
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0`
```

Comment: I tried to execute the command in the directory with Ghost. And came out this error:

Answer (score 2):

From your output it seems to me that you are not in the Ghost install directory. Could you please try to `cd` to the directory where the source of Ghost is located and run the command again?

Comment: There's still a problem.